# How to add a new XAML "Page", and its associated code-behind files, in C++/WinRT in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

There are various related questions that give a hint how to **add a new XAML `Page` properly to a WinRT/C++ project in Visual Studio**, but none are specific to C++/WinRT. (I.e, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32673327/how-to-add-a-new-xaml-view-with-code-behind), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452353/how-do-i-add-a-second-code-behind-file-to-a-xaml-file), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44342724/re-link-xaml-and-code-behind-in-visual-studio-solution).)

Further, though WinRT/C++ is a great improvement over C++/CX (in my opinion), almost all Microsoft documentation uses either C# or C++/CX as examples.

To make matters worse, as of the date of this posting, **when you use the Add Item feature in Visual Studio to add a XAML `Page`, it creates the page in C++/CX** even for WinRT/C++ projects.

Finally, there is (as of this date) no documentation provided by Microsoft for how to add a new XAML `Page` to a WinRT/C++ project, at least that I can find (see first paragraph).

Ugh.

To save others potentially hours, I have pieced together the hints and succeeded in properly adding a new XAML `Page` to a Visual Studio WinRT/C++ project.

I am asking and answering the question: **How do you add a new XAML `Page` to a WinRT/C++ project in Visual Studio?**

---

**Addendum**

I was missing the obvious! It turns out you **can** use Visual Studio to trivally add a WinRT/C++ XAML `Page`.  Despite looking as carefully as I (thought) I could.

The (easy) correct answer is given in answer #2.

**But I'll keep this question and answer up** - in case anyone else blunders down the same path and can't find the option to add a XAML `Page` in WinRT/C++ in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3):

I was missing the obvious!

It turns out you can use Visual Studio to trivally add a WinRT/C++ XAML Page.

Despite looking as carefully as I (thought) I could through the options in Visual Studio's editor, I missed the location of the XAML template for WinRT/C++ projects.

So, for completeness, I'll paste screenshots.

---

Here is how you add a new XAML `Page` to an existing WinRT/C++ project, spelled out in painful detail.

**Step 1**: Right-click on the solution, and navigate through the menu/submenus to `Add New Item...`

[image]

**Don't select the XAML node.**

...Keep the ROOT NODE selected:

[image]

Here's what it looks like if you select the 'XAML' node in the `Add New Item...` entry:

[image]

---

**Bottom line**

I lost a few hours because I assumed that it was a good idea to click on the 'XAML' node in the `Add New Item...` dialog to filter down to just XAML-related templates.

Unfortunately, the XAML template for the WinRT/C++ version of the component is not present in that list (as of the day I write this).  You have to click on the root node to see it.

I will leave my other answer up, in case it's useful to anybody.

But this answer describes the (trivial) correct way to add a new XAML `Page` to a WinRT/C++ project - use the Visual Studio editor to `Add New Item...`, as expected.

Comment: You should probably report this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/xlang/issues), too.

Answer (score 1):

To save others potentially hours, I have pieced together the hints and succeeded in properly adding a new XAML `Page` to a Visual Studio WinRT/C++ project.

Here is the answer.

Pictures are worth thousands of words, so here are the steps.

- Save and close your project in Visual Studio
- Manually open the `.vcxproj` and `.vcxproj.filters` files in a text editor

[image]

- Assume we already have the default page, `MainPage.xaml` and its associated `.idl` and code-behind files.  In the following steps, we will create a new XAML page and its associated files called `LoginPage`.
- No need to actually create the **files** for `LoginPage` yet - we'll do that in the final steps.  Just edit the `.vcxproj` and `.vcxproj.filters` files for now.
- In both of these two files, we will copy **every block** that contains a reference to `MainPage` and modify it to read `LoginPage`.
- Start by editing the `.vcxproj` file

[image]

**Block 1**: code-behind dependency for the `LoginPage.cpp` - `LoginPage.xaml` relationship

We start with this:

[image]

...Modify the block to add a section for `LoginPage`, resulting in this:

[image]

**Block 2**: code-behind dependency for the `LoginPage.h` - `LoginPage.xaml` relationship

We start with this:

[image]

...Modify the block to add a section for `LoginPage`, resulting in this:

[image]

**Block 3**: Let Visual Studio know to use the Designer for `LoginPage.xaml` (I think!)

We start with this:

[image]

...Modify the block to add a section for `LoginPage`, resulting in this:

[image]

**Block 2**: code-behind dependency for the `LoginPage.idl` - `LoginPage.xaml` relationship

We start with this:

[image]

...Modify the block to add a section for `LoginPage`, resulting in this:

[image]

- Proceed to edit the `.vcxproj.filters` file

[image]

**Block 1**: Tell Visual Studio to include `LoginPage.xaml` in Solution Explorer (I think!)

We start with this:

[image]

...Modify the block to add a section for `LoginPage`, resulting in this:

[image]

**Block 2**: Tell Visual Studio to include `LoginPage.idl` in Solution Explorer (I think!)

We start with this:

[image]

...Modify the block to add a section for `LoginPage`, resulting in this:

[image]

**Block 3**: Tell Visual Studio to compile `LoginPage.cpp` as part of this project (I think!)

We start with this:

[image]

...Modify the block to add a section for `LoginPage`, resulting in this:

[image]

- You're done editing the `.vcxproj` and `.vcxproj.filters` files.  Save and close them.
- The rest is simple.  Create all four `LoginPage` files by simply copying the `MainPage` files.

We start with these files in the project:

[image]

...after copying the 4 (highlighted) `MainPage` files, and renaming them to `LoginPage`, we end up with these files:

[image]

- For the final step, you must actually open up each of the four new `LoginPage` files **in a text editor** (not Visual Studio) and do a **search-and-replace** for the text `MainPage` and replace with `LoginPage`.

  In the search, **DO** match on capitalization, but **DO NOT** match on 'whole-word only' (i.e., there are some data types that have `MainPage` as part of the name, such as `MainPageT`, and these must also be searched-and-replaced).

  I won't bore you by pasting screenshots of the actual source code files.
- Once you have replaced all occurrences of `MainPage` with `LoginPage` in the four files noted, save and close the file.
- You're done!

Open the solution in Visual Studio, and notice the beauty:

Solution Explorer now shows our `LoginPage.xaml` file along with its code-behind files, properly nested:

[image]

...and pressing F7 to build the project results in a successful build:

[image]

...and it successfully runs, as well - unchanged from what it did before.

**This is because, of course, you haven't DONE anything with `LoginPage` yet** - it doesn't appear in your user interface - but it's available for use in code and I'll let you take it from here!

As grateful as I am that Microsoft has released the excellent WinRT/C++ functionality - it is rather ... frustrating ... to say the least - that as of this date there is **no way to add a new XAML `Page` to a WinRT/C++ project** using Visual Studio standard tooling (such as the `Add Item` option), so far as I can see.  It is further... frustrating... that there is also no documentation whatsoever that explains how to do it (that I can find).

I sure hope that my question and answer become irrelevant very soon and that Microsoft adds both tooling and documentation re. adding a new XAML `Page` to an existing WinRT/C++ project in Visual studio.

Or maybe I'm mistaken?  Maybe it's already possible to do this easily, and I just couldn't find it?

I hope this helps someone, though, just in case!